# PHP not properly configured

Tags: server, php, html

I just installed php.5.1.2 on ubuntu server.

I tried to run simple test:

```
<? phpinfo() ?>
```

it displayed the information but, also display the html tags:

```
</table><br />
<h2>PHP License</h2>
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" width="600">
<tr class="v"><td>
<p>
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE
</p>
<p>This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
</p>
<p>If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.
</p>
</td></tr>
</table><br />
</div></body></html>
```

I compiled from source. I did not find a good way to remove it.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: How did you do your test? Did you run `php` from the commandline?

Comment: yes php test.php from command

Comment: Basically looks like you have nothing that converts the HTML - which may be a MIME type error, or simply something improper about how you access the file - could you specify how you get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the default MIME type is wrong.  It's being interpreted as text/plain when it should be interpreted as text/html. I have not compiled from source.  From the package(s) I've installed, there's a stanza in the three files /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini and /etc/php5/cli/php.ini which reads:

```
PHP's built-in default is text/html
; http://php.net/default-mimetype
default_mimetype = "text/html"
```

Comment: does this affect the way php runs? I am having issue with connections to Database?